# Double integral in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: integration

I have been trying to solve the following double integration

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}^{}\int_{\mathbb R^n}^{} e^{-|x|^4}e^{-|y|^4}|x-y|^{-b}dxdy$$

Where $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $0<b<n$.

I know how to do it for square powers of $|x|$ and $|y|$ but can't find the appropriate substitution for fourth powers.

Comment: Do you mean $n=2$?  Otherwise, what do you mean by integrating a function of $x$ and $y$ over all of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: $x$ and $y$ are vectors. Normal mathematical notation.

Comment: Ah, maybe you should use $\|x\|$ and $\|y\|$ notation.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Oftentimes mathematicians use a single bar instead of a double one, for brevity and in order to avoid an overloaded notation. One quickly gets used to this.

Comment: Are you asking for the evaluation of this integral, or merely for the study of its convergence? Prior to attempting to study it myself I tried computing it for $n=1$ with Mathematica 7 and it didn't succeed. Nevertheless, it managed to compute the integral with powers of $2$ instead of $4$, which suggests that your integral does not have an explicit form expressible in known functions.

Comment: @alex I am trying to evaluate this integral. Powers of 2 is doable by hand and I succeeded in doing it. How can I be sure that this integral can't be expressed explicitly, apart from Mathematica's inability to do it.